# OnBackButtonPressed() is not getting fired for the second time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When i clicked backbutton in a particular page for the first time it works perfectly but after opening the same page for the second time its not working( i have set a debugger but not called).

It shows the alert message that i wrote on the page1.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
            if (result)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
        });
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

In the next page2

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
        return true;
    }
```

when i click the back button for the second time it shows the alert message that i wrote in the Page 1 Back button functionality

This code works good for the First time not for the rest of the times

How to get rid of it, please help me out.

**Note** I have used the bottomNavigation bar for xamarin Android

https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/

Comment: We need to see what you did to help you out...

Comment: Post some code so that we can help you out.

Comment: I have updated my Code

Comment: The problem is `OnBackButtonPressed()` is getting overridden. Are you using Tabbed page or Carousal page.?!

Comment: Yeah i'm using tabbed page from this reference"https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/"

Comment: Ok., now it becomes tricky. What happens if you remove the `OnBackButtonPressed()` from the page2.?!

Comment: @Ramya Yes i'm using that

Comment: @Senthamizh behaves as same.

Comment: @nandha May I know why you are using RemovePage instead of PopAsync to move back to Page1?

Comment: @Ramya to remove from the stack

Comment: @Ramya Previously I have used the PopAsync but no improvement show that RemovePage

Comment: @nandha Can you check if you are navigating from Page1 to Page2 second time?

Comment: Yes I'm navigating

Answer (score 1):

Ok., implement a condition inside the `OnBackButtonPressed()` like this.

```
OnBackButtonPressed()
{
   var pagesinstack = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count();
   int count = pagesinstack;
   Debug.WriteLine("stack history {0}", count.ToString());
     if (count <= 1)
     {
        /* Your exit code here */
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
      {
        var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
        if (result)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
      });

      return base.OnBackButtonPressed();

     }
     else
     {
        Navigation.RemovePage(this);
        return true;
     }
}
```

Note : `OnBackButtonPressed()` is a boolean function, so `return true` or `false` according to your requirement.

Comment: My issue is Backbutton is not getting called while i'm clicking the phone's backbutton for the second time

Comment: Dude., remove OnBackButtonPressed from the second page and give a try like I mentioned above...

Comment: Yeah Dude ,i have tried the code that you gave but i works like the same.its(BackButton) not getting fired

Comment: Try using this code only in MainPage.cs / App.cs of your application. Or use the same code in both the pages (thats not a professional way though)